# Visual Studio Code can't connect to internet. As if proxy settings were set

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

Just installed visual studio code. I need to install plugins but it can't connect to the internet. It gives the error `connect ETIMEDOUT 50.0.0.5:8080`

The thing is; `50.0.0.5:8080` is a proxy that I need to use sometimes. I set it from `Network > Network proxy` and I set it to `Manual` and `Apply system wide`. But now I have it set to none! How is it trying to connect to that proxy? *I've seen a similar issue before*

How do I disable that ghost proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally it worked. Fixed it using `dconf-editor`

*(if you don't have it then `sudo apt install dconf-editor`)*

open it and go to `system > proxy` there's `ftp`,`http`,`https` and `socks`. Just set them all to default (button on the bottom right).